# Create new column based on values in 2 other columns

Tags: r

I am new to R and am trying to create a new column based on 2 other columns in the data frame.

```
UserID    Age    GradeLevel
 001       10       5
 002       10       3
 003       8        4
 004       10       7
 005       8        3
 006       8        NA
 007       10       6
 008       7        NA
 009       7        6
```

I have to create a new column "Grade". I need to first look at the age and then GradeLevel. If the assigned GradeLevel is correct then I copy the same GradeLevel to the new column. If the assigned grade level is wrong (like in obs 2, 4, 6, 8, 9) then I have to assign the users to the higher grade according to their age.

For example a 10 years old child can be in Grade 5 or 6, but if the GradeLevel is not either 5 or 6 then assign to Grade 6 (higher grade of the 2).

So the desired output should be like this:

```
UserID    Age    GradeLevel    Grade
 001       10       5            5
 002       10       3            6
 003       8        4            4
 004       10       7            6
 005       8        3            3
 006       8        NA           4
 007       10       6            6
 008       7        NA           3
 009       7        6            3
```

GradeLevel is a factor in the data, but we can covert it to character if need be. In the data I have all the GradeLevels from K thru 12.
I am trying to use the ifelse statement, but cannot get it to work.

```
test$Grade.f = ifelse(test$age==10 & (test$GradeLevel %in% c(5,6)), test$GradeLevel, "6")
               ifelse(test$age==9 & (test$GradeLevel %in% c(4,5)), test$GradeLevel, "5").....
```

Please I need some help with this problem.

Comment: You don't mention any rule to assign grade level. Maybe you assume that your local system is an international one.

Comment: The Grade Levels are assigned according to this Wikipedia article. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_the_United_States

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Age=10:7, Lowerlevel=5:2, Upperlevel=6:3)
library(dplyr)
res <- left_join(df,df1, by="Age")
 df$Grade <- with(res, ifelse(is.na(GradeLevel)|GradeLevel< Lowerlevel|GradeLevel>Upperlevel,
                          Upperlevel, GradeLevel))
 df
 #  UserID Age GradeLevel Grade
 #1      1  10          5     5
 #2      2  10          3     6
 #3      3   8          4     4
 #4      4  10          7     6
 #5      5   8          3     3
 #6      6   8         NA     4
 #7      7  10          6     6
 #8      8   7         NA     3
 #9      9   7          6     3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(UserID = 1:9, Age = c(10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 
10L, 7L, 7L), GradeLevel = c(5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 3L, NA, 6L, NA, 
6L)), .Names = c("UserID", "Age", "GradeLevel"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: @Kabir Thanks.  I am not sure if the `Lowerlevel` is needed.

Comment: Great!! It worked and you made the code simple enough for person line me to understand. Thanks so much @akrun.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach:

```
# identify invalid values
invalid <- with(test, abs(Age - 4.5 - "[<-"(GradeLevel, is.na(GradeLevel), 0)) > 0.5)

# replace invalid values with default values
test$Grade <- ifelse(invalid, test$Age - 4, test$GradeLevel)

test
#   UserID Age GradeLevel Grade
# 1    001  10          5     5
# 2    002  10          3     6
# 3    003   8          4     4
# 4    004  10          7     6
# 5    005   8          3     3
# 6    006   8         NA     4
# 7    007  10          6     6
# 8    008   7         NA     3
# 9    009   7          6     3
```

Comment: Maybe simple , but 4.5 , 4 look a little bit odd!

Comment: +1 looks interesting, but, I don't know how you got the `4.5` fixed.

Comment: @akrun The value `4.5` is the mean of the valid differences between age and level (i.e., `4` and `5`).